# Is there a way to write multiple dictionaries with different keys to the same excel sheet using python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, export-to-excel

I have multiple dictionaries with different keys in each dictionary. For eg,

```
dict A = {
    'a' = 'a',
    'b' = 'b'
}
dict B = {
    'x' = 'x',
    'y' = 'y',
    'z' = 'z'
}
dict C = {
    'a' = 'a',
    'm' = 'm',
    'z' = 'z'
}
```

Is there a way to write this into an excel sheet one below the other, something like:

| a | b |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b |  |
| **x** | **y** | **z** |
| x | y | z |
| **a** | **m** | **z** |
| a | m | z |

I tried converting it into a list of dictionaries and creating a dataframe using pandas, but it adds all the keys of all dictionaries to the first row, something like:

| a | b | x | y | z | m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append all of your data to a list `[[keys],[values],[keys],...]` and then read it as a DataFrame, that way each entry of the list would be a separate row in the data frame. You can then convert the data frame to an excel.

```py
dict_list = []

for dd in [dictA, dictB, dictC]:
    dict_list.append(list(dd.keys()))
    dict_list.append(list(dd.values()))


df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict_list)

df.to_excel('dict_data.xlsx', index=False, header=False)
```